# Redirect doesn´t work using variable codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

Hello friends I have one problem with redirect function if I try this it´s works I get to redirect to google.es

```
redirect('http://www.google.com');
```

but if I try this

```
$url= 'http://www.google.com';
redirect($url,'refresh');
```

i obtain this http://127.0.0.1/mywebfolder/http://www.google.com

how i could to fix? thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776247/why-redirect-function-in-codeigniter-not-working

Comment: This link may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542770/codeigniter-redirect-to-another-url-from-view-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading this

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Then do the redirect

```
$url= 'http://www.google.com'; redirect($url,'auto');
```

Auto is usually default so your don't need to use it you can just use
  $url= 'http://www.google.com'; redirect($url);

Comment: To make the helper available through your application go to cofig/autoload.php.  and add url in the helper array

Comment: Thanks friend using this  works but if i get the url from a database i have the same problem `$url = $this->model->get_link();` `redirect($url,'auto');` codeigniter redirect me with the same problem how could i fix it getting the url from a database?

Comment: A dude just do a var_dump on $url.  Its should be in the form of a array

Comment: Unless in your model you've returned the URL properly

Comment: $URL[0]->thecolumnname

Comment: the result of the database are in array i fix the problem using implode function and convert the result into string, thanks friends